# Horizontal UISwipeGestureRecognizer in subview of UIScrollView ? (UIScrollView only needs to recognize vertical scrolling)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView where I added a subview. The scrollview scrolls fine vertically and that is all it should do. I would now like to recognize left/right swipes in the subview with the help of a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. I know it is possible, but I have not come across a solution and several tries have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 5):

Try these:

- Set the delegate of your `UIGestureRecognizer` and
- Implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`:

  ```
  -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
  return YES;
  }
  ```
- Implement `shouldReceiveTouch`:

  ```
  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
  {
   return YES;
  }
  ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope, I have tried that before, without success :(. I think the UIScrollView just swallows every drag that is detected.

Comment: Are you sure you implemented shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer and not only shouldReceiveTouch?

Comment: Have you checked if your delegate methods get called?

Comment: Yes I did implement `-shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer::` but strangely they do not get called...

Comment: Are you setting the delegate correctly? Are you adding the gestureRecognizer to the UIScrollView?

Comment: No, I am not adding the gesture recognizer to the UIScrollView because I want it only to be recognized when I do the gesture in the subview. Adding it to the scrollview would not make any sense, right ?

Comment: I think the problem is really that I have nested the subview in many other views. Is there a way to let the touches all the way through ?

Comment: So I have a scrollview where I add a content view and in this content view I add the subview where I would like to detect touches. So the swipe has to basically go through the content view

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish something related (adding a two-finger swipe gesture recognizer directly on the scroll view) with the new iOS 7 UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
        shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return otherGestureRecognizer == scrollView.panGestureRecognizer;
}
```

However, the results were not perfect - the delay waiting for the swipe gesture recognizer to fail first causes a lag in the scrollview's pan gesture recognizer getting its touches, so normal scrolling is noticeably delayed when you start to scroll.